# Functors preserving $\Gamma$-colimits are coreflective?

Tags: ct.category-theory

An article by Kennison

> On limit preserving functors, Illinois J. Math. Volume 12, Issue 4 (1968), 616-619.

States the following

> Th. Let $C$ be a small category. Then $[C,\text{Set}]_{\Gamma}$ is  a reflective subcategory of $[C,\text{Set}]$.

where by $[C,\text{Set}]_{\Gamma}$ he means those functors preserving $\Gamma$-limits for $\Gamma$ a class of cones.

Is it possible to dualize this theorem in the following way:

> Conj. Let $C$ be a small category. Then $[C,\text{Set}]^{\Gamma}$ is  a coreflective subcategory of $[C,\text{Set}]$.

where by $[C,\text{Set}]^{\Gamma}$ I mean those functors preserving $\Gamma$-colimits for $\Gamma$ a class of cocones.

But is this dualization sound?

In this case $[C,\text{Set}]^{\Gamma}$  would be the category of fixed points of a suitable comonad $T:  [C,\text{Set}] \to [C,\text{Set}]$.
(A fixed point of $T$ is an object such that $T(X)\cong X$ via the counit of the comonad.)

I am even more interested in knowing if the following is true.

> Hope. Is the $[C,\text{Set}]^{\Gamma}$ the category of the fixed points of a pointed (not copointed!) endofunctor $T:  [C,\text{Set}] \to [C,\text{Set}]?$

Comment: I think your conjecture follows from the adjoint functor theorem. It suffices to check that $[C,Set]^\Gamma$ is accessible, and you can write it as a pullback of accessible categories.

Comment: That sounds right to me.  It's closed under colimits because colimits commute with colimits, and it's accessible since it is the category of models of a (colimit) sketch.

Comment: Thanks Mike! That was my argument too. What do you think about the *hope*?